# Taylor series for $\sqrt[3]{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the Taylor series for $\sqrt[3]{x}$, but since the *n-th* derivative of the function $$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$$
not definded at $x=0$, I've swithched to $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+1}$, This is my Attempt:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{x+1}=1+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{2x^2}{9\cdot2!}+\frac{10x^3}{27\cdot 3!}-\frac{80x^4}{81\cdot4!}+...$$

but when i plug $x=125 \iff \sqrt[3]{x+1}=\sqrt[3]{126}$ i get something way bigger than the acttual value which is about $5.01...$, you can check it [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/1%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%5Cleft(125%5Cright)%7D%7B1!%7D%2B%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B-2%7D%7B9%7D%5Cleft(125%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B10%7D%7B27%7D%5Cleft(125%5Cright)%5E%7B3%7D%7D%7B3!%7D%2B%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B-80%7D%7B81%7D%5Cleft(125%5Cright)%5E%7B4%7D%7D%7B4!%7D%5Cright)).

But I can't find the mistake in the equation.

Comment: See the [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: What is the condition of existence of this series ?

Comment: This looks correct, but it will only give nice values for smaller $x$. Try plotting it along with $f(x)$ to see what's going on.

Comment: @VIVID - Are there any restrictions on $x$? Because in my book the author says if $s\in \mathbb R^+$ and $-1<x<1$ then the expression using the binomial coefficient for $(1+x)^s$ is valid.

Comment: Your fist four terms are correct. There is also a more concise way to look at fractional powers of $(1+x)4 for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Try a series centered around $x=125$

Comment: What do you mean ? @Deane

Comment: Taylor series centered at $x= 125$

Comment: Good idea but you should change the center every time @Deane

Comment: @Yassir, yes, that's the point of a problem like this, which is pretty standard in calculus courses. The point is that you're trying to compute the value of a function for an input that's close to an input for which you already know the output or can easily calculate it. Here, that's $x = 125$. The point is that you do not always want to use the Taylor series centered at $x = 0$, because $x = 125$ is too far away. And, if you want to use the binomial series, you have to rewrite the function in a way so that  the key part of the formula looks like $(1+t)^p$, where $t$ is small.

Comment: If $x=125$, then clearly $-1<x<1$ is not satisfied...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write the $n$th term exactly as

$$ R_n(x) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} $$

where $( a )_{n} = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a-k$ is a falling factorial. The ratio

$$ \biggr|\frac{R_{n}(x)}{R_{n-1}(x)}\biggr| = |x|\biggr|\frac{4}{3n} - 1\biggr| \to |x| $$

so the series definitely does not converge for $|x| > 1$ by the ratio test.

---

If you want a method of computing cube roots effectively, the paper [*A Way of Approximation of a Cube
Root*](http://ajmonline.org/2008/5.pdf), 2018 by By Mohammad H. Poursaeed has your back:

$$\sqrt[3]{x} \approx \frac{k}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{4x-k^3}{12k}}$$

where $k$ is chosen such that $k^3 < x < (k+1)^3$.

In your example, $x = 126$, and so $k = 5$, giving

$$\sqrt[3]{126} \approx \frac{5}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{4(126)-5^3}{12(5)}} = 5.013297966\cdots$$

while $\sqrt[3]{126} = 5.013297935\cdots$ in actuality. It's quite spectacularly close, and very fast (as long as you have a fast method for computing square roots).

Answer (score 2):

For $x\gt 1$, expand in terms of $\frac1x<1$ to ensure convergence

$$\sqrt[3]{x+1}= \sqrt[3]{x} \sqrt[3]{1+\frac1x}
= \sqrt[3]{x}  (1+\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{2}{9\cdot2!}\frac1{x^2}+\frac{10}{27\cdot 3!}\frac1{x^3}-\frac{80}{81\cdot4!}\frac1{x^4}+...)
$$

Then, set $ x=125$ to obtain the approximation
$$\sqrt[3]{126} =5(1+\frac1{3\cdot 125}-\cdots )=5.0133$$

Comment: Well, It works only if you know what is $\sqrt[3]{x}$ or if $x$ is a perfect cube.

Comment: It’s not a show-stopper; one can always find the nearest cube for any number for approximation.

Comment: @Yassir, if you were asked to estimate $\sqrt[3]{126}$, then it *is* near a perfect cube, so this is the best way to approximate it.

Answer (score -1):

The binomial series for $(a+x)^\alpha$ is only valid if the absolute value of x is smaller than one, unless $\alpha$ is a non-negative integer. Your value is x=125>>1 and $\alpha$ is not integer, thus the divergence. To get a good approximation you would have to expand around $x_0=125$, which of course requires knowledge of the third root of 126.

Comment: did you read the comments? @Rohbar

Comment: I should have, sorry, but in this case why did you not answer your own question yet if you know the answer already?

Comment: I didn't know whether this caused the divergence (I'm not the one who gave you (-1)) @Rohbar